# How to profile ASP.NET/IIS Pipeline

Tags: asp.net, performance, autocomplete, profiling, real-time

I have an autocomplete service that executes in under 1ms - perfect! This is a timing of the method.

When I built this service outside of the project, the service call would take a total of 5ms. The service is a ASMX, and returns a JSON result.

But once I integrated this service into the real project it now takes 200ms, although the method call is actually still executing in 1ms. So it must be serialization, ASP.NET pipeline or IIS.

The project is so big it's hard to know exactly what HttpModules/Handlers are running.

So my question is, is there a simple profiler a can place on a HTTP request in IIS that will tell me how long each stage takes?

BTW this all on my local box, before anyone says network speed!

Many Thanks,
Ash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/), but for status code 200:

[image]